# How to convert text 36 1/2 to 36.5 in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a column that is having a value 36 1/2 it is stored as character varying.from postgresql function i need to convert this text to 36.5 to match the actual value.How do i convert text '36 1/2' to 36.5 in postgresql ?

Comment: Is `1/2` the only fractional component present, and is `36 1/2` the most complex use case?  By the way, the best way to handle this would be to fix your data source so you don't need to do any complex massaging in Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH f(n) AS
   (SELECT *
    FROM regexp_matches('36 1/2', '^([\d.]+)( +(\d+)/(\d+))*$'))
SELECT CASE
          WHEN n[2] IS NULL
          THEN n[1]::float8
          ELSE n[1]::float8 + n[3]::float8 / n[4]::float8
       END
FROM f;
```

Comment: It is working for 36 1/2 but it fails for 36 0 or 36

Comment: Nobody would write "36 0", surely? That's nonsensical. And it's easy to make the fractional part match conditional...

Comment: @ShamseerPC You didn't ask for `'36'` to be converted, but anyway, I have updated the solution.